# Perl questions regarding unpack() and the v flag in printf()

Tags: perl, for-loop, printf, pack, unpack

I am trying to accomplish the following:

For an arbitrary Perl string (whether or not it is internally encoded in UTF-8, and whether or not it has the UTF-8 flag set), scan the string from left to right, and for every character, print the Unicode code point for that character in hex format. To make myself absolutely clear: I do not want to print UTF-8 byte sequences or something; I just would like to print the *Unicode code point* for every character in the string.

At first, I have come up with the following solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use warnings;
use utf8;
use feature 'unicode_strings';

binmode(STDOUT, ':encoding(UTF-8)');
binmode(STDIN, ':encoding(UTF-8)');
binmode(STDERR, ':encoding(UTF-8)');

$Text = "\x{3B1}\x{3C9}";
print $Text."\n";
printf "%vX\n", $Text;

# Prints the following to the console (the console is UTF8):
# αω
# 3B1.3C9
```

Then I have seen some examples, but without reasonable explanations, which made me doubt that my solution is correct, and now I have got questions regarding my own solution as well as the examples.

1) Perl's documentation about the v flag in (...)printf says:

"This flag tells Perl to interpret the supplied string as a vector of integers, one for each character in the string. [...]"

It does not say what it exactly means by "a vector of integers", though. When looking at the output of my example, it *seems* that those integers are the Unicode code points, but I would like to have this confirmed by somebody who knows for sure.

Hence the question:

1) Can we be sure that every integer which is pulled from the string that way is the respective character's Unicode code point (and not some other byte sequence)?

Secondly, regarding an example which I have found (slightly modified; I can't remember where I got it from, maybe from the Perl docs):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use warnings;
use utf8;
use feature 'unicode_strings';

binmode(STDOUT, ':encoding(UTF-8)');
binmode(STDIN, ':encoding(UTF-8)');
binmode(STDERR, ':encoding(UTF-8)');

$Text = "\x{3B1}\x{3C9}";
print $Text."\n";
printf "%vX\n", $Text for unpack('C0A*', $Text);

# Prints the following to the console (the console is UTF8):
# αω
# 3B1.3C9
```

Being a C and assembly guy, I just don't get why somebody would write the `printf` statement like shown in the example. According to my understanding, the respective line is syntactically equivalent to:

```
for $_ (unpack('C0A*', $Text)) {
  printf "%vX\n", $Text;  
}
```

As far as I have understood, `unpack()` takes `$Text`, unpacks it (whatever that means in detail) and returns a list which in this case has one element, namely the unpacked string. Then $_ runs through that list with one element (without being used anywhere), hence the block (i.e. the `printf()`) is executed once. In summary, the only action which is done by the above snippet is executing `printf "%vX\n", $Text;` one time.

Hence the question:

2) What could be the reason for wrapping this into a for loop like shown in the example?

Final questions:

3) If the answer to question 1) is "yes", why do most examples I have seen use `unpack()` after all?

4) In the three line snippet above, the parentheses which surround the `unpack()` are necessary (leaving them away leads to syntax errors). In contrast, in the example, the `unpack()` does not need to be enclosed in parentheses (but it does not harm if they are added nevertheless). Could anybody explain the reason?

**Edit / Update in reply to ikegami's answer below:**

Of course, I know that strings are sequences of integers. But

a) There are many different *encodings* for those integers, and the bytes which are in a certain string's memory area depend on the encoding, i.e. if I have two strings which contain exactly the same *character sequence*, but I store them in memory using different encodings, the *byte sequences* at the strings' memory locations are different.

b) I strongly suppose that (besides Unicode) there are many other systems / standards which map characters to integers / code points. For example, the Unicode code point 0x3B1 is the Greek letter α, but in some other system, it may be the German letter Ö.

Under these circumstances, the question makes perfect sense IMHO, but I possibly should be more precise and reword it:

If I have a string `$Text` which only contains characters which are Unicode code points, and if I then execute `printf "%vX\n", $Text;`, will it print the *Unicode* code point in hex for every character *under all circumstances*, notably (but not limited to):

- regardless of Perl's actual internal *encoding* of the string
- regardless of the string's UTF-8 flag
- whether or not `use 'unicode_strings'` is active

If the answer is yes, what sense do all the examples make which are using `unpack()`, notably the example above? By the way, I now have remembered where I got that one from: the original form is in Perl's `pack()` documentation, in the section about the C0 and U0 mode. Since they are using `unpack()`, there must be a good reason for doing so.

**Edit / Update No. 2**

I have done further research. The following proves that the UTF8 flag plays an important role:

```
use Encode;
use Devel::Peek;

$Text = "\x{3B1}\x{3C9}";
Dump $Text;
printf("\nSPRINTF: %vX\n", $Text);
print("UTF8 flag: ".((Encode::is_utf8($Text)) ? "TRUE" : "FALSE")."\n\n");

Encode::_utf8_off($Text);
Dump $Text;
printf "\nSPRINTF: %vX\n", $Text;
print("UTF8 flag: ".((Encode::is_utf8($Text)) ? "TRUE" : "FALSE")."\n\n");

# This prints the following lines:
#
# SV = PV(0x1750c20) at 0x1770530
#   REFCNT = 1
#   FLAGS = (POK,pPOK,UTF8)
#   PV = 0x17696b0 "\316\261\317\211"\0 [UTF8 "\x{3b1}\x{3c9}"]
#   CUR = 4
#   LEN = 16
#
# SPRINTF: 3B1.3C9
# UTF8 flag: TRUE
#
# SV = PV(0x1750c20) at 0x1770530
#   REFCNT = 1
#   FLAGS = (POK,pPOK)
#   PV = 0x17696b0 "\316\261\317\211"\0
#   CUR = 4
#   LEN = 16
#
# SPRINTF: CE.B1.CF.89
# UTF8 flag: FALSE
```

We can see that `_utf_off` indeed removes the UTF8 flag, but leaves the string's bytes untouched. `sprintf()` with v flag outputs different results, solely dependent on the string's UTF8 flag even if the string's bytes remain the same.

Comment: For question 3, the context of the for in  `printf "%vX\n", $Text for unpack('C0A*', $Text);` is a statement modifier syntax which has the syntax `for LIST`. Where as in the 3 line snippet is a control block. syntax is different. `LABEL for VAR (LIST) BLOCK` you can read up on these in the perlsyn section of the perl doc under compound statements and statement modifiers

Comment: You are almost correct about the equivalent `for` loop, but `unpack` returns a *list* of values so inside the loop would be `printf "%vX\n", $_`. However the template for `unpack` is very odd. A `C` rule takes the code point of the next character and returns it as an integer, however with a repeat count of 0 it will have no effect at all. Then the `A` rule returns a character string, and with a repeat count of `*` it just returns all of the rest of the object string. In other words, `unpack 'C0A*', $Text` is simply `$Text`. This is either broken or deliberately obfuscated code

Comment: To your question #1, I found this reference to the "v" flag in the book "Programming Perl" 3rd ed...  The "v" flag is useful for displaying ordinal values of characters in arbitrary strings:
      printf "version is v%vd\n", $^V;          # Perl's version
      printf "address is %*vX\n", ":", $addr;   # IPv6 address
      printf "bits are %*vb\n", " ", $bits;     # random bitstring

Comment: Can you please say more explicitly what you mean about removing the parentheses from the `unpack` call? I wouldn't expect it to make any difference here and my tests confirm that

Comment: The `%v` format is meant for handling Perl version numbers. The output is a sequence of code points separated by dots. `%vX` gives the numbers as upper-case hex, `%vx` gives lower-case hex, and `%vd` gives decimals. You can probably also use `%vb` for binary and maybe others, but they make little sense

Comment: @Chris Doyle: Thanks for the answer. I didn't notice that when reading perldoc perlsyn. You are completely right, and it is mentioned explicitly in the docs.

Comment: @Borodin (comment #4): if I modify the three line snippet so that the first line reads `for $_ unpack('C0A*', $Text) {` (notice that the surrounding parentheses around `unpack()` are now missing), Perl won't compile the script and throw a syntax error, at least in my configuration. Thanks to Chris Doyle's explanation, I now have understood why.

Comment: @Borodin (comment #5): I don't think so. According to the docs, the v flag can generally be used to display the integers / ordinal values from arbitrary strings; see Perl's documentation for `sprintf()` and tale852150's comment..

Comment: @Borodin (comment #2): You are right in that `unpack()` returns a list - sorry for missing that. I have updated my question accordingly. Regarding the template, the C0 has another meaning than you might think: It turns on the "character mode" (as opposed to "byte mode"); see the section about C0 mode and U0 mode in Perl's `pack()` documentation.

Comment: In your "Update 2", `Encode::_utf8_off($Text);` should be `my $orig_Text = $Text; Encode::_utf8_off($Text); die("Invalid test") if $orig_Text ne $Text;`

Comment: Why? Encode's documentation states that two string's probably won't be considered equal by Perl if one of them has the UTF8 flag set and the other hasn't, so that code probably will die. In that sense, the strings are different. But that hasn't been my question. My question was if sprintf() will behave differently with two identical strings *solely* depending on the UTF8 flag. I should have said more clearly what I mean by identical; coming from C and assembly, of course I consider two strings identical if their byte sequence is identical, regardless of some flags.

Comment: Because it's obvious that passing different things will result in different output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sprintf '%vX'` has no knowledge of code points or UTF-8. It just returns a string representation of the characters of the string. In other words,

```
sprintf('%vX', $s)
```

is equivalent to

```
join('.', map { sprintf('%X', ord($_)) } split(//, $s))
```

That means it output `s[0]`, `s[1]`, `s[2]`, ..., `s[length(s)-1]`, in hex, separated by dots.

It returns the characters (integers) of the string regardless of the state of the `UTF8` flag. That means that how the string is stored (e.g. whether the `UTF8` flag is set or not) has no effect on the output.

```
use Encopde;

$Text1 = "\xC9ric";
utf8::downgrade($Text2);

printf("Text1 is a string of %1\$d characters (a vector of %1\$d integers)\n",
   length($Text1));
print("UTF8 flag: ".((Encode::is_utf8($Text2)) ? "TRUE" : "FALSE")."\n");
printf("SPRINTF: %vX\n\n", $Text1);

$Text2 = $Text1;
utf8::upgrade($Text2);
print($Text1 eq $Text2
    ? "Text2 is identical to Text1\n\n"
    : "Text2 differs from Text1\n\n");

printf("Text2 is a string of %1\$d characters (a vector of %1\$d integers)\n",
   length($Text2));
print("UTF8 flag: ".((Encode::is_utf8($Text2)) ? "TRUE" : "FALSE")."\n");
printf "SPRINTF: %vX\n\n", $Text2;
```

Output:

```
Text1 is a string of 4 characters (a vector of 4 integers)
UTF8 flag: FALSE
SPRINTF: C9.72.69.63

Text2 is identical to Text1

Text2 is a string of 4 characters (a vector of 4 integers)
UTF8 flag: TRUE
SPRINTF: C9.72.69.63
```

---

Let's change the code in your question to show relevant information:

```
use Encode;

$Text1 = "\x{3B1}\x{3C9}";

printf("Text1 is a string of %1\$d characters (a vector of %1\$d integers)\n",
   length($Text1));
printf("SPRINTF: %vX\n\n", $Text1);

$Text2 = $Text1;
Encode::_utf8_off($Text2);
print($Text1 eq $Text2
    ? "Text2 is identical to Text1\n\n"
    : "Text2 differs from Text1\n\n");

printf("Text2 is a string of %1\$d characters (a vector of %1\$d integers)\n",
   length($Text2));
printf "SPRINTF: %vX\n\n", $Text2;
```

Output:

```
Text1 is a string of 2 characters (a vector of 2 integers)
SPRINTF: 3B1.3C9

Text2 differs from Text1

Text2 is a string of 4 characters (a vector of 4 integers)
SPRINTF: CE.B1.CF.89
```

It shows that `sprintf '%vX'` will have different output for different strings, which is no surprise, since `sprintf '%vX'` simply outputs the characters of the string. You could just as easly have used `uc` instead of `_utf8_off`.

---

1. If for two identical strings, `sprintf '%vX'` altererd its output based on the `UTF8` flag, it would be considered to suffer from *The Unicode Bug*. Most instances of those has been fixed (though `sprintf` never suffered from this bug).

Comment: Please see my updated question. Regarding the parentheses, I hadn't noticed that the Perl's documentation explicitly explains when to use them and when not.

Comment: I think my update *did* add something new. Imagine guys like me who are worried by the subject and come to this question via Google. I think they will be grateful for the clarifications and for making clear the difference between code points and encoding one more time. Furthermore, I have mentioned where I found the example which uses `unpack()` and the weird `for ...` construction, and, since that example is from a very serious source (namely the Perl documentation), that I would like to know why they are doing it that weird way. Nevertheless, accepting your answer ...

Comment: After further research, it seems that your answer is not completely correct. I explicitly had asked if it would work whether or not the UTF8 flag is set, and you have said yes. This is not correct. After removing the UTF8 flag from `$Text`, `printf "%vX\n", $Text;` prints out the *UTF-8 byte sequence* of `$Text` (and not the Unicode code points).

Comment: I'll look thoroughly into your updated example later. But (although not having the example studied yet) I still think I'm not completely mistaken. I did the following: `perl -e 'use Encode; $Text = "\x{3B1}\x{3C9}"; printf("%vX\n", $Text); Encode::_utf8_off($Text); printf("%vX\n", $Text);'`, and this prints the Unicode code points in the first line and the UTF8 bytes in the second one. I know that one shouldn't turn off the UTF8 flag the way I did (and in fact, I never have done this in production code), but it seemed the easiest way to turn it off just as an experiment.

Comment: 1) Yes, I never use _utf8_off in production; I was just curious what would happen. 2) Are you saying that `Encode::_utf8_off($s)` does an *implicit* `encode_utf8($s)` as well? I doubt ... Rather, Encode's docs seem to imply that the bytes in memory which represent a string are *not* touched by doing Encode::_utf8_off (in fact, this seems to be the main reason to avoid that). Well, it seems it's time to follow your advice and to use Devel::Peek.

Comment: I have edited my question. Please see Update 2 for what I am meaning. My example seems to contradict this equivalence unless I have misunderstood something. By the way, in case it matters, this is on Perl 5.14.2.

Comment: The update adds the proof an important thing which has been claimed to be untrue: `sprintf()` with v flag behaves differently on identical strings, solely depending on the UTF8 flag (I hope you agree with me that strings are identical if their integer sequence, as shown by Devel::Peek's Dump, is identical).

Comment: I think I am right, and all of it finally makes sense to me. Perl's internal encoding for strings mostly is UTF8, and the example string's byte sequence in UTF8 is `CE B1 CF 89` (hex), which is `316 261 317 211` (octal). The latter exactly is what `Dump()` prints out in *both* cases. This proves that the string's byte sequence is left untouched when removing its UTF8 flag. But depending on that flag, Perl's functions and operators like `sprintf()`, `length()`, `eq` etc. interpret the string differently. Switch Perl to byte mode, and you will get a length of 4 for both strings.

Comment: I didn't pretend that. I just said that the byte sequence shown by the PV is the UTF8 byte sequence of my example string (i.e. Perl's internal representation of the string minus the flags and other "metadata"). When the UTF8 flag is on, Perl knows that this byte sequence is a UTF8 encoded Unicode string, and thus `sprintf()` outputs the Unicode code points. When the UTF8 flag is off, the byte sequence is just a byte sequence (sort of an ASCII / EBCDIC string) for Perl, and thus `sprintf()` outputs the single bytes.

Comment: Regarding your Java string, it of course contains 3 characters, but six bytes. Regarding my Perl string, it contains 2 characters immediately after creating it (the UTF8 flag is on in that moment), but it contains 4 bytes. As long as the UTF8 flag is on, the four bytes are two Unicode code points encoded in UTF8 from Perl's point of view. If the UTF8 flag is turned off, the same four bytes are a) just a sequence of single bytes or b) an ASCII / EBCDIC string from Perl's point of view, where a) and b) are the same thing in Perl.

Comment: Your are mistaken. My example clearly demonstrates the opposite. Your example strings "abc" and "\xA1\xA2\xA3" are not appropriate for demonstration for the following reasons: The strings can be represented unambiguously, i.e. they are ASCII strings as well as byte sequences at the same time, and for the ASCII chars, the ASCII code is identical to the Unicode code points. Thus, you can't see the influence of the UTF8 flag with the strings you are using.

Comment: My example shows the influence of the UTF8 flag in *this* case. Of course, sprintf() returns code points with UTF8=0 and bytes with UTF8=1, but *only* if the string can be encoded *unambigiously*, i.e. as long as the Unicode code points are *identical* to the ASCII code.

Comment: I think the same about you. Your example doesn't prove anything: `Encode::is_utf8("\x{20_000}")` yields TRUE, so obviously Perl treats that like a Unicode string; it has set the UTF8 flag and has encoded the (invalid) string into UTF8 (byte sequence `F0 A0 80 80`). Since the UTF8 flag is set, `sprintf()` turns the UTF8 byte sequence back to the code point (even if it is invalid) and print that. This is logic because Perl knows that the string can't be encoded *unambiguously*. If you remove the UTF8 flag from the string, `sprintf()` prints the single bytes.

Comment: As for your second example, that doesn't prove anything either: From `sprintf()'s` output, you can't decide if it returns a code point or a byte at all because the code point and the ASCII code (byte) are identical anyway.

Comment: **The UTF8 flag doesn't affect `sprintf '%vX'`'s behaviour. It always output the characters of the string.** All you've shown is that passing different strings to `sprintf '%vX'` result in different output. DUH!

Comment: In what way was my statement contradicted? All I have claimed was that `sprintf()'s` changes if the UTF8 flag is set / removed on a string which *otherwise is left untouched*. All of my examples clearly demonstrate that. None of my comments were off-topic since that exactly was part of the question; none were wrong (as my examples (and yours) clearly show).

Comment: You're lying by pretending the bytes to which the `PV` points is the string. `eq`, `length`, `Dump` and `sprintf '%vX'` all show that `_utf8_off` changed the string.

Comment: **The UTF8 flag *does* affect `sprintf()'s` behavior.** If you remove it from a string using Encode::_utf8_off(), and the string originally contained at least one Unicode code point above 255, `sprintf()` prints the string's UTF8 bytes (instead of the code points like before removing the flag).

Comment: I am not lying. I hopefully have made very clear what I consider an "otherwise unaltered string". And of course are the bytes to which the PV points the string in the sense that they are the UTF-8 encoded Unicode code points of the string, i.e. they are Perl's internal representation of that string (in conjunction with the UTF8 flag and maybe other metadata which was not subject of my question).

Comment: And that's the key point: if I do encode_utf8 to a string which already is encoded in UTF8, the bytes representing the string will *not* be changed, with the exception of the flag(s), but `sprintf()` will yield other results. For somebody who is coming from C / Assembler, this is surprising.

Comment: So you are calling me a liar? Then show me which code in my question shows that I was knowing that the string changed. If you can't, you are the liar.

Comment: Hey, I just saw that you have edited my question and my code. I am very upset about that. This is absolutely insolent. First you edit what I wrote, and then you lie and tell the world that I have written that. Please undo your edits immediately. And secondly, thank to your edits not remembering what exactly I wrote, it should have been absolutely clear that I meant "The output differs"; maybe I have made a mistake there. But that doesn't change anything regarding the actual subject.

Comment: I just wanted to know if `sprintf()'s` output would be identical for two strings which are **identical with the exception of the UTF8 flag**. Seems that this is impossible in your opinion, but it was my question. You said yes, but the answer is no.